# Guessing game loop in Python

Tags: python

When I attempt to create a looping guessing game, which essentially allows multiple guessing to find the answer, I have print which tells the person if the number guessed was too low or too high. My problem is that it always tells the person too high no matter the input from 100 down to 1, it always says the input is higher than the randomized number.

I am fairly new to Python so I am unsure what else to try. I added an input below each while statement to stop the print from repeating endlessly, as I learned it will, but I cannot seem to get it to actually be anything but higher than the random number.

```py
from random import randint
randomNum = randint(1,100)
print('Guess the number, 1 through 100!')
input()
while str(input) < str(randomNum):
    print('Your number is lower, try again!')
    input()
while str(input) > str(randomNum):
    print('Your number is higher, try again!')
    input()
if input == randomNum:
    print("You Win!")
```

I simply need to know how to change it so it actually works the way its supposed to. When a number is guessed, it tells the person too low or too high, and allows as many guesses as it takes to solve.

Comment: When you followed this program's execution using a debugger, at what point did it first behave differently than you expected?

Comment: `str(input)` is `'<built-in function input>'`. You need to assign the result of `input()` to a variable and work on that.

Comment: Why not comparing numbers instead of strings?

Answer (score 0):

## alternative 1

```py
from random import randint

randomNum = randint (1, 100)
number = float ( input ( 'Guess the number, from 1 to 100!' ) )

while number != randomNum :
    if number < randomNum :
        number = float ( input ( 'Your number is lower, try again!' ) )
    else :
#    elif number > randomNum : # can be ignored because `number` is different from `randomNum` and therefore either lower or higher.
        number = float ( input ( 'Your number is higher, try again!' ) )

print ( 'You Win!' )
```

`input` is a *function* with a *return value* and an *argument*. The **argument** is what to print (incase of `input`) on the standard output. In your case, it's what the player is supposed to see.
The **return value** is what can be (and normally is) stored in a variable as `str`. In your case, `number` is the return value.

## alternative 2

```py
from random import randint

randomNum = randint (1, 100)
number = float ( input ( 'Guess the number, from 1 to 100!' ) )

while number != randomNum :
    if number < randomNum :
        s = 'lower'
    else :
#    elif number > randomNum : # can be ignored because `number` is different from `randomNum` and therefore either lower or higher.
        s = 'higher'
    number = float ( input ( 'Your number is', s + ', try again!' ) )

print ( 'You Win!' )
```